# remove Â from word pad document after writing from java

Tags: java, wordpad

taking a string from java and placing it into a text file.  When the string is written it does not contain Â, however when the string comes open in word pad the character appears.

String without:

```
 Notice of Appeal:

 
 Hamilton City Board of Education
```

String with:

```
 Notice of Appeal:
 Â 
 Â 
 Hamilton City Board of Education
```

Below is the write string

```
out = new BufferedWriter (new FileWriter(filePrefix + "-body" + ".txt"));
                    out.write("From:        " + em.from);
                    out.newLine();
                    out.write("Sent Date:   " + em.sentDate);
                    out.newLine();
                    out.write("Subject:     " + em.subject);
                    out.newLine();
                    out.newLine();
                    out.newLine();
                    String temp = new String(emi.stringContent.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8");
                    out.write(temp);
```

What should i do to not have them appear in word pad?

Comment: Something is happening behind the scenes that you will need to stop. I'm not sure for the life of me how we'll be able to guess what it is based on your post however. You will probably need to give us much more information and pertinent code, preferably an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: It is an encoding issue. Make sure you are using UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a UTF-8 encoding problem to me.  I believe you are getting the `Â` character because you are writing the content in UTF-8, and the content contains a high-ASCII value, but WordPad is expecting the data to be in the code-page your local system is running in.  Either write the content in the code-page expected by WordPad, or make WordPad expect UTF-8.

As an aside:

```
String temp = new String(emi.stringContent.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8");
out.write(temp);
```

is a complete waste of time; use:

```
out.write(emi.stringContent);
```

instead.

Comment: how do i make word pad expect that?

Comment: thanks for the aside...it was like that at first but i was trying everything possible to make it work!

Comment: Oh, and it looks like your JVM's default encoding is UTF-8, hence why writing a String with FileWriter is doing UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: what other formats could i write it in and keep the formatting?

Comment: You could try ISO 8859-1 (aka Windows-1252).  Or you could try writing a BOM at the beginning of the file, which *may* cause WordPad to recognize it as Unicode.  Or you could try explicitly specifying UTF-8 when opening the file.

Comment: Now i am stuck with a utf 7 conversion problem...thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming this is a line separator issue.
use:

```
String line = System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

and just add it to your string wherever you want a new line

Comment: that does not do the trick...it is saved as a string with "\\n" for a new line and appears without the charater in the debugger, but appears when it is saved

Comment: you only need "\n" to create a newline

Comment: the extra is for the escape in java

Comment: why do you want to escape the newline character? it is still necessary for the file.

Comment: Why does the edit you have not show the string you provided in the first part of question as this would make it more clear?

Comment: that string provided is emi.Stringcontent

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with the line-break encoding; it's a UTF-8 encoding issue.

Comment: how to do i go about fixing that encoding issue so it opens properly in word pad? or should i save it as a doc?